# Is it possible for an individual to refuse a cheque in France?

Tags: check, payment, france, legal-tender

Some shops in France do not accept cheques (anymore or never have).

Is it legal for an individual in France to refuse payment by cheque as well? In other words, is it possible to force someone (an institution or company) to use a specific payment method (specifically wire transfer) instead of a cheque?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any country, individuals (and shops) can reject any form of payment that is not *Legal Tender* - defined by law as a payment form that must be accepted.

Shops are typically more generous, because they want to do business with you, but individuals are in a different position.

In France, only official coins and bills are declared as *Legal Tender* (so if they don't want to, individuals don't even need to accept bank transfers).

This is for doubts you need to pay.

In addition, as *you are not forced to do business with them*, people and shops can require whatever they feel like to require - if you want to buy their car, they can ask you to stand on your head and spit coins, and if you don't like it, they don't sell to you. (They won't do much business then, probably)

Comment: Legal tender only applies in the first place if settling a debt, e.g. if you've already had the service before paying, like in a restaurant. If you are offering to buy goods in a supermarket they can reject any form of payment they like.

Comment: That's what I mean in the last paragraph - the are free how and with whom they do business, and they can even reject you.